# Rails - How to accept ajax in your controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an ajax call that should be updating a record using my controller. However, I am having difficulty trying to access it.

I can see via the logs that the data is being sent to the controller but I am not sure how to get at it.

The data in ajax is being sent via json.

```
data = JSON.stringify(foo)
```

In the logs, I can see `{'name' => 'test', 'type' => 'object'}`

I tried to do

```
data = @params[:data]
```

but I kept getting`nil` errors. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: You can specify that your route accepts json in config/routes.rb.  Then you can use: respond_to |format|  in your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why `data = @params[:data]`?

`@params` is an instance variable, which is `nil` until assigned some value. You can check in your console

```
@foo
#=> nil
```

however, controllers have `params` at your disposal which contains the `body` all required parameters in the request, so you just have to do

```
params[:name]
#=> test
```

Answer (score 0):

name = params[:name]
type = params[:type]

or

## js code:

$.post({
    url: xxx,
    data: {
        data: { name: 'xxx', type: {blalalala} }
    }
})

## ruby

data = params[:data]